# Atomic exchange of two std::atomic<T*> objects in a lock-free manner in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

The following code is a skeleton of an atomic pointer class taken from a simulated annealing application in the [PARSEC benchmark suite for shared-memory multiprocessors](http://parsec.cs.princeton.edu/overview.htm).

In that application, the central data structure is a graph (more specifically, a netlist of an integrated circuit). Each node in the graph has an attribute indicating its physical location. The algorithm spawns many threads and each thread repeatedly and randomly selects two nodes and exchanges their physical locations if that results in better routing cost for the chip.

Because the graph is huge and any pair of nodes can be chosen by each thread, the only workable solution is a lock-free concurrent data structure (CDS). That's why the following `AtomicPtr` class is crucial (it is used to atomically exchange pointers to two physical location objects in a lock-free manner).
The function `atomic_load_acq_ptr()` is a defined in assembly code and corresponds closely to `std::atomic<T*>::load(memory_order_acquire)`.

I want to implement that CDS using C++11 atomics.

```
template <typename T>
class AtomicPtr {
  private:
    typedef long unsigned int ATOMIC_TYPE;
    T *p __attribute__ ((aligned (8)));
    static const T *ATOMIC_NULL;
    inline T *Get() const {
        T *val;
        do {
            val = (T *)atomic_load_acq_ptr((ATOMIC_TYPE *)&p);
        } while(val == ATOMIC_NULL);
        return val;
    }
    inline void Swap(AtomicPtr<T> &X) {
        // Define partial order in which to acquire elements to prevent deadlocks
        AtomicPtr<T> *first;
        AtomicPtr<T> *last;
        // Always process elements from lower to higher memory addresses
        if (this < &X) {
            first = this;
            last  = &X;
        } else {
            first = &X;
            last  = this;
        }
        // Acquire and update elements in correct order
        T *valFirst = first->Checkout(); // This sets p to ATOMIC_NULL so all Get() calls will spin.
        T *valLast  =  last->PrivateSet(valFirst);
        first->Checkin(valLast); // This restores p to valLast
    }
};
```

The `std::atomic<T*>::exchange()` method can only be used to exchange a bare `T*` pointer with a `std::atomic<T*>` object. How to do exchange of two `std::atomic<T*>` objects in a lock-free manner?

What I can think of is that the `AtomicPtr` class below can itself be based on `std::atomic<T*>` by declaring:

```
std::atomic<T*> p;
```

and replacing all `atomic_load_acq_ptr()` calls by `std::atomic<T*>::load(memory_order_acquire)` and replacing all `atomic_store_rel_ptr()` calls by `std::atomic<T*>::store(memory_order_release)`. But my first thought was that `std::atomic<T*>` should replace `AtomicPtr` itself and there may be a clever way to exchange `std::atomic<T*>` objects directly. Any thoughts?

Comment: There is no way to atomically swap the contents of two `std::atomic`s in C++11.

Comment: actually, I don't think that this is even possible on x86 / x64

Comment: It is not possible directly. But the `AtomicPtr` class already does it by following a check-out\check-in discipline:
1- Any thread that wants to do a swap first checks out the pointer (by writing a sentinel value called `ATOMIC_NULL` above) and, when done, checks it in.
2- Any thread that wants to read (i.e., Get()) the pointer value has to keep spinning if the pointer has been checked out.

Comment: @AhmedNassar: why not replicate this logic with `std::atomic<T*>` ?

Comment: @Matthieu: This is what I am already suggesting as the only solution I could come up with. I was looking for better solutions :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that the simpler way to get what you wish is to replicate the logic that you have seen here.

The problem is that there is no possibility to get an atomic operations across two atomic objects, so you have to follow a procedure:

- order the atomics (to avoid dead-locks)
- "lock" all but the last one (increasing order)
- perform the operation atomically on the last one
- perform the operation and "unlock" the others one at a time (decreasing order)

This is, of course, quite imperfect:

- not atomic: whilst you are busy locking a variable, any of the not yet locked could change state
- not obstruction free: if for some reason a thread is blocked whilst having locked a variable, all other pending threads are also blocked; be careful to avoid deadlocks here (should you have other locks)
- brittle: a crash after locking a variable leaves you stranded, avoid operations that may throw and/or use RAII to "lock"

However it should work relatively well in practice in the case of only 2 objects (and thus one to lock).

Finally, I have two remarks:

- in order to lock you need to be able to define a sentinel value, `0x01` usually works well for pointers.
- the C++ Standard does not guarantee that `std::atomic<T*>` be lock-free, you can check this for your particular implementation and platform with `std::atomic<T*>::is_lock_free()`.

Comment: As I suggested in the question, porting the `AtomicPtr` class to use C++11 atomics instead of the custom-defined assembly-level functions was the only solution I had.
The `AtomicPtr` class is in fact crafting its own spin lock by spinning whenever the pointer holds the sentinel value.
But thanks a lot for elaborating on the imperfections of the suggested solution. I am using it as a benchmark, not in production code. BTW, the original code was already defining the sentinel value exactly as you suggested:
`template<typename T>
const T *AtomicPtr<T>::ATOMIC_NULL((T *)((int)NULL + 1));`

Comment: @AhmedNassar: for portability reasons, I would advise you to cast `NULL` to `intptr_t` instead of `int`; `int` is often only 32 bits in 64 bits code.

Answer (score 4):

The closest you can come without a spinlock is:

```
std::atomic<T> a;
std::atomic<T> b;
a = b.exchange(a);
```

Which is thread safe for `b`.

`a` may not be concurrently accessed.

Comment: This is not atomic because `std::atomic<T>::exchange()` accepts a bare `T` value not a `std::atomic<T>` object. Hence, it will first invoke `a`'s conversion function to `T` and then pass it to `b.exchange()`.

Comment: I never said it was atomic for `a`, it is only atomic for `b`. Which is the best you can achieve without a spin-lock.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out a CAS (compare and swap ) operation?

```
   std::atomic<T*> v;

      while(!v.compare_exchange_weak(old_value,new_value, std::memory_order_release, memory_order_relaxed))
```

Comment: But the `new_value` parameter in `std::atomic<T*>::compare_exchange_weak()` is a bare `T*` not a `std::atomic<T*>` object. If that bare `T*` value was previously read from a `std::atomic<T*>` object, the exchange is not gonna be atomic. Do I miss something here?