# Why can't std::atomic<T> be swapped?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, standards, atomic

```
#include <atomic>

int main()
{
    auto a = std::atomic_int(1);
    auto b = std::atomic_int(2);

    std::swap(a, b); // error
}
```

error message:

> error: no matching function for call to 'swap(std::atomic&, std::atomic&)'

**Why can't `std::atomic<T>` be swapped?**

Comment: swapping via `std::swap` wouldnt be atomic, but then I wonder why it has no member `swap`...

Comment: It's not required to be atomic when I swap them.

Comment: Related? [Atomic exchange of two std::atomic<T*> objects in a lock-free manner in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349688); _"The problem is that there is no possibility to get an atomic operations across two atomic objects, [...]"_.

Comment: why use `atomic` in the first place when its not required to be atomic? Consider two threads swapping at the same time. The individual reads and writes are atomic, but the result after the swap can be messed up

Comment: e.g. in a move-ctor and a member variable is atomic. @idclev463035818

Comment: Could you describe some scenario where non-atomic swap of two atomic objects makes sense in practice, when other threads read/write these objects simultaneously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two levels to that issue.

First is plain simple and technical - `std::atomic` is not move constructible or move assignable as mentioned in other answer.

Second is the rationale behind this - swapping `std::atomic`s would not be atomic in itself. And since `std::atomic`s are used in multithreaded environments adding `swap` would have lead to wide range of bugs due to possible misunderstandings (that since there is `swap` for `std::atomic` then it is atomic in itself).

All in all - if you don't need atomic `swap` this can be pretty easily done using mentioned `exchange`s.

Comment: As per your last paragraph, I feel like it becomes slightly a motivation issue. What's more important - `std::swap` basically double moves in every case **or** it just swaps two values? If the latter, I see no reason not to implement it exactly as two `exchange` calls. Not trying to find the answer here, but trying to state the potatial issue loud.

Answer (score 5):

`std::atomic` has a deleted copy constructor, and doesn't have a move construtor.

Therefore it is neither *move assignable* nor *move constructible*.

Therefore `std::swap` cannot be called on any `std::atomic` type.

Reference:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap

Comment: How about `a.exchange(b.exchange(a));`?